# Suds is not caching wsdls

Tags: suds

I 'm using Suds for RPC calls over SOAP, and the client refuses to cache between calls (resulting in waiting 30+ seconds waiting for the client to initialise). Can anyone see what needs to be done in addition to the below in order for caching to be enabled?

```
client = Client(WSDL_URL)
cache = client.options.cache
cache.setduration(days=10)
cache.setlocation(SUDS_CACHE_LOCATION)
```

Comment: WSDL file is 22KB (suds also goes to download all of the referenced schema which increases the load time)

Comment: If you save the WSDL to a local file and load it from Suds, does that improve the loading time?

Comment: Nope, still the same. Saved into the suds location by going to 'save as' and saving with the same filename. Not sure if there's any other info that suds requires when it's looking for cache hits?

Comment: Can you show us the WSDL URL or file?

Comment: Sure thing - the WSDL is at https://training-api.temando.com/schema/2009_06/server.wsdl

Comment: The first time I did `from suds.client import Client; client = Client('https://training-api.temando.com/schema/2009_06/server.wsdl')` took 30+ seconds, the second time it was very fast.

Comment: was a file created in the path indicated in setlocation?

Comment: Could you post your code so I can compare to what I have?

Comment: Only this: `from suds.client import Client; client = Client('https://training-api.temando.com/schema/2009_06/server.wsdl')`

Comment: If you were doing this from a Windows machine, then you probably had the same problem I did. Here's the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038226/suds-is-not-reusing-cached-wsdls-and-xsds-although-i-expect-it-to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a bug in the library itself. The cache file needs to be written in binary mode. That can be fixed in cache.py:

1) In FileCache.put(), change this line:

```
f = self.open(fn, 'w')
```

to

```
f = self.open(fn, 'wb')
```

2) In FileCache.getf(), change this line:

```
return self.open(fn)
```

to

```
return self.open(fn, 'rb')
```

For more details, see:

[Suds is not reusing cached WSDLs and XSDs, although I expect it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038226/suds-is-not-reusing-cached-wsdls-and-xsds-although-i-expect-it-to)